# How to resolve warning: extra tokens at end of #undef directive [enabled by default]

Tags: c, gcc

As part of our build, we have a generated conf.h file which contains line like :

```
#undef something-notdefined
```

The warning is for the column where "hyphen" is present. The conf.h contains many number of lines with hyphen and for all the lines these warnings are thrown .

undef directive name should not contain hypen ; is it the right inference from the above warnings ?

Comment: What is the actual real line containing your `undef` ? What is the actual `conf.h` line? How is it generated? By what tools???

Comment: CONFIG_TARGET_ENABLE_ETHERNET-PHY is one such example .

Comment: How was that particular line generated? You cannot `#define CONFIG_TARGET_ENABLE_ETHERNET-PHY` (you'll better put a space before the `-` and that would mean to define `CONFIG_TARGET_ENABLE_ETHERNET` as `-PNY`

Comment: We have a configuration file and as per the selection/deselection, we have the following format "#define <option> 1" or #undef <option>

Comment: Why do you have the hyphen? It should not be here.

Comment: That is the macro name which I cannot change. Some of the config options has hyphen. After conf.h is generated, code is working but too much of warning during build for all the lines having hyphen .

Comment: A **macro name cannot have hyphens** in it. You have to change that.

Comment: Also marcos **may only** start with a letter or an underscore: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7608200/694576. `<` and `>` are not allowed as characters in a macro name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should code a comment after the `#undef` like

```
 #undef something /*something-notdefined*/
```

And you should change your `conf.h` generating machinery so that it generated valid C code with valid `#define` or `#undef` directives.

Recall that a macro name starts with a letter (or a `_` which is frowned upon) and contains letters, digits, underscore.

You need to change your `conf.h` generator so that its conform to the rules.